# PHP Error Reporting with config

Tags: php

Hi im trying to block certain error_reporting things upon a config variables

```
<?php

$config['warnings'] = false;
$config['errors'] = false;

if (!$config['warnings'])
{
     error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
}
if (!config['errors'])
{
     error_reporting(0);
}
?>
```

But as you can see when i do another opening error_reporting statement it would replace the old one. How can i block to but only if booth configs are true and only one if only one config is set to true?

Comment: shouldnt you manage this in php.ini ?

Comment: The reasons i want to do this is because i want to code my own error system

Comment: @Pogrindis I would not know how to do that :/

Comment: but you should write you're own no ? Changing sys php.ini vars incode seems wrong ..

Comment: @Pogrindis This is actually not uncommon to modify `error_reporting()` at runtime.

Comment: What is your goal? If `$config['errors'] == false`  report no errors of any severity, while if `$config['warnings'] == false` to report errors but not `E_WARNING`?

Comment: Bassicly errors means if it shows errors and warnings is if it shows warnings

Comment: @user3684526 But `warnings` when `true` should show errors _and warnings_ (which would make sense)? The way you just said it, if `warnings` is true, you would only warnings but not other errors (which is atypical and doesn't quite make sense). Sorry - we just need you to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach this as nested logic.  First check `$config['errors']` and enable or disable `error_reporting` with `E_ALL` or `0`.

Then *subtract* `E_WARNING` from the `error_reporting` setting by calling `error_reporting()` inside to get the current value.

```
if ($config['errors']) {
  // Enable all
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  // Then subtract warnings from the current value
  // by calling error_reporting() as its own argument
  if (!$config['warnings']) {
    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_WARNING);
  }
}
else {
  // Or disable everything.
  error_reporting(0);
}
```

You don't specifically mention `E_NOTICE` but I suspect you want those disabled too.

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE);
```

If you wish to start with something a little less than `E_ALL`, you may want to remove `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_STRICT`

```
if ($config['errors']) {
  // Enable all (but a little less than all)
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
  // Then check warnings, etc...
}
```